How to dynamically replace value with jq in bash
I'm trying to get a value from the Json and add it to another field of the same json file. I need to do it in a lot of file so I'm using a loop:
for i in $(find . -name \*.txt); do 
    valorAPoner=$(cat $i | jq -r .Name); 
    tmp=$(mktemp);
    jq -r '.Authentication.ExternalProvider.LdapUserAndDomain |= "$valorAPoner"' $i  > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" $i.json; 
done

But when I open $i.json it shows me:
{
  "Name": "dsfdsf",
  "FullName": "xxxxx",
  "Authentication": {
    "ExternalProvider": {
      "LdapUserAndDomain": "$valorAPoner"

I see the string literal of the variable (valorAPoner) but  I need the value of the variable. Do you know how to answer it?
Thanks

This might help: Passing bash variable to jq

Are you surprised by this? Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only in double quotes.

btw, for i in $(find ...) is itself buggy; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29
